# Create a rewrite rule to prevent a file from appearing except on one subdomain

Tags: htaccess, web-hosting

I have wildcard hosting set up on `*.example.com`, and I’d like to have a certain file appear on one specific subdomain only. I'd like to create a rewrite rule that prevents it from appearing on the other subdomains.  What’s the `.htaccess` code for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To block a file from being accessible on all but one subdomain you could do something like the following near the top of your root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Block requests to file from other subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/to/file\.ext$ - [R=404]
```

The above states... whenever the file `/path/to/file.ext` is requested and the requested `Host` does not start `subdomain.` then trigger a "404 Not Found" response (as if the file didn't exist). This means that the stated file is only accessible when requested via the specific subdomain.

- `^path/to/file\.ext$` - this is a regular expression that matches the URL-path being requested. Note there is no slash prefix on the URL-path being matched when used in `.htaccess`.
- `!^subdomain\.` - the `!` prefix negates the expression that follows (in this case a regex). So, this is successful when the regex `^subdomain\.` does *not* match the requested `Host` header (ie. `HTTP_HOST`).

However, you don't necessarily need to use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) for this. You could use an [Apache expression](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) and mod_alias (Apache 2.4 and later versions of LiteSpeed). For example:

```
# Block requests to file from other subdomains
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} !~ /^subdomain\./">
    Redirect 404 /path/to/file.ext
</If>
```

The `!~` operator is a negated regex match. ie. does not match the stated regular expression (delimited with slashes).

---

*Previous answer (before edit):*

<s>The same as any other rewrite, except that you check the requested `Host` header for the subdomain in a *condition*. For example, using mod_rewrite in the root `.htaccess` file:</s>

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^path/to/source-file\.ext$ path/to/target-file.ext [L]
```

---

#### Reference

- [Apache mod-rewrite Documentation - Contents](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/)
- **[Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)**
- [Apache mod_rewrite Reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

  - [`RewriteRule` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)
  - [`RewriteCond` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: Thanks. Why are there 2 files in the bottom line?

Comment: @RyderCragie The "2 files" were to rewrite the request from one to the other on a specific subdomain. However, it would seem (from your revised question) that that is not actually what you were wanting to do? (Although if it wasn't then why was the answer "accepted"?) I have rewritten my answer to reflect your revised question. There are no rewrites here, so there is now just "1 file in the bottom line".

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Oooo, that's a completely different question! I've _rewritten_ my answer.

Comment: Just to clarify what I meant here, as this is also wrong.

When someone visits test.example.com, I want it to show a specific file in the directory, but only for that one subdomain specified in the .htaccess file.

Comment: @RyderCragie So the file is not requested in the URL-path? Only when `https://test.example.com/` (the hostname only) is requested then `file.ext` is served? What if `https://test.example.com/file.ext` is requested directly? Should that file also be served? What if `https://test.example.com/another-file.ext` is requested?